# sharing profile2 fields multisite

Tags: 7, users, entities

I have a site with 2 multi site like

```
abc.com
xyz.abc.com
zxy.abc.com
```

All sites have same drupal 7 code base. and I shared all users successfully across all portals.

my setting file for sub-site looks like this

```
$main_database_prefix = 'abc.com.';
$current_database = 'xyz';
$databases = array (
  'default' =>
  array (
    'default' =>
    array (
      'database' => $current_database,
      'username' => 'xxxx',
      'password' => 'xxxx',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => array(
              'default'   => '',
              'users'     => $main_database_prefix,
              'sessions'  => $main_database_prefix,
              'role'      => $main_database_prefix,
          'role_permission'      => $main_database_prefix,
              'users_roles'   => $main_database_prefix,
              'user_ips'   => $main_database_prefix,
              'user_profile_details' => $main_database_prefix,
              'price' => $main_database_prefix,
              'transaction' => $main_database_prefix,
          'db_roles' => $main_database_prefix,
          'user_modification_history'=>$main_database_prefix,
          'authmap'=> $main_database_prefix,
          'user_industry'=>$main_database_prefix,
          'user_account_request'=>$main_database_prefix,
          'user_account_details'=>$main_database_prefix,
          'country'=>$main_database_prefix,
          'states'=>$main_database_prefix,
          'discount'=>$main_database_prefix,
          'taxname'=>$main_database_prefix,
          'price'=>$main_database_prefix,
          'transaction'=>$main_database_prefix,
          'field_data_field_subscriber_name'=>$main_database_prefix,
          'field_revision_field_subscriber_name'=>$main_database_prefix,
          'profile'=>$main_database_prefix,
          'profile_type'=>$main_database_prefix,

    )
    ),
  ),
);
```

all tables working properly , except

```
'field_data_field_subscriber_name'=>$main_database_prefix,
      'field_revision_field_subscriber_name'=>$main_database_prefix,
      'profile'=>$main_database_prefix,
      'profile_type'=>$main_database_prefix,
```

I can not see these fields on registration page or in backend
The only difference is these table are entity reference table.

I googled things a lot for this but no success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by adding 2 more tables

```
'field_config_instance'=>$main_database_prefix,
'field_config'=>$main_database_prefix,
```